# What is java.constructors.single()?

Tags: java, kotlin, kotlin-script

I'm learning Kotlin how to eval scripts, and I saw the code in [BasicJvmScriptEvaluator](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/libraries/scripting/jvm/src/kotlin/script/experimental/jvm/BasicJvmScriptEvaluator.kt#L91) like the following:

```
    val ctor = java.constructors.single()

    val saveClassLoader = Thread.currentThread().contextClassLoader
    Thread.currentThread().contextClassLoader = this.java.classLoader
    return try {
        ctor.newInstance(*args.toArray())
    } finally {
        Thread.currentThread().contextClassLoader = saveClassLoader
    }
```

I don't understand the code `java.constructors.single()`, there is no package named java.constructors. How should I understand this code?

Answer (score 5):

It's important to realize you're in an [extension function](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html#extension-functions) operating on an instance of [`KClass`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect/-k-class/). So the `java` is actually an invocation of `this.java` which returns the `java.lang.Class` associated with the `KClass`. Then the `constructors` gets an array of `Constructor`s from the `Class` and `single()` gets the one (and only, else an exception is thrown) element in that array.

If you expand the code into multiple lines it may be easier to see what's going on:

```kotlin
val clazz: java.lang.Class = this.java // 'this' is an instance of kotlin.reflect.KClass
val ctors: kotlin.Array<Constructor> = clazz.constructors
val ctor: java.lang.reflect.Constructor = ctors.single()
```

The `single()` function is [an extension function defined on `Array` (and other types)](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/single.html).